# Setup has detected that the file "" has changed since it was initially published

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, setup-deployment

I have developed a setup application for my project, wherein prerequisite software will be downloaded from the vendor's website. Doing this I got a crystal reports error when I try to install that application, saying  `Setup has detected that the file "" has changed since it was initially published`.

[image]

Targeted framework of my application: `.NET Framework 3.5`
and developed in `Visual Studio 2010`

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222109/error-downloading-prerequisites-after-publishing-clickonce-application-from-vs-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definately a problem with the CRE. See the steps below:

> 1. In the following folder, you will find a product.xml file. \Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal
>      Reports 4.0\
> 2. Open the product.xml file in Notepad (or any text editor) and under the  section, you will find 2 URLs that point to the 2
>      deployment packages.  Copy each URL into your web browser and manually
>      download the packages.
> 3. Once the packages are downloaded, copy them to the same folder as the product.xml file (see #1 above).

Comment: okay since I am setting prerequisite software's to download from vendor`s website, still I have to make above changes..??

Comment: Yes you still need to make the changes.

Comment: On windows 10 path should be C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\