# Why do I see a ClickOnce Dependency Error?

Tags: visual-studio, vsto, clickonce

I have a Visio VSTO addin that has a dependency on a EULA. I am building and deploying using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10. This was working fine, up until the time I had to rebuild a Windows 10 dev machine.

The EULA depndency is installed under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages
```

In Visual Studio 2019 I can see and select the dependency that is deployed when I publish the plugin. However, when trying to install the ClickOnce addin from the product site I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Setup has detected that the file 'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD8AA0.tmp\cpaseulapackage\en/cpas-eula.txt' has either changed since it was initially published or may be corrupt.
```

In Visual Studio the 'Sign the ClickOnce manifests' and 'sign the assembly' options are checked.

I can't figure out what has changed, or caused the deployment to break. Any thoughts would be gratefully received.

Thanks and regards
Andrew

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind and it works, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just Refer to Alec's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18466367/16764901).

I made some modifications based on your situation, please try and tell me the effect.

> 1. In the following folder, you will find a product.xml file. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\cpaseulapackage
> 2. Open the product.xml file in Notepad (or any text editor) and under the section, you will find 1 or 2 URLs that point to the deployment package. Copy each URL into your web browser and manually download the packages.
> 3. Once the packages are downloaded, copy them to the same folder as the product.xml file (see #1 above).