# ClickOnce install error: "changed since initially published."

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I have a trouble getting a `ClickOnce`, C#, Visual Studio application to install. I get the following error (retyped):

```
Setup has detected that the file
C:\...\Reportviewer.exe
has changed since it was initially published.
Click OK to retry the download or Cancel to exit Setup.
```

I deleted the previously existing `Reportviewer`, but the error persists. I'm doing this install via VPN (if it matters). What does this actually mean, and what  can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I took the ReportViewer prerequisite (and all the other prerequisites, too) out of the published version. We install ReportViewer from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4016

Answer (score 0):

You say that you've deleted the previously existing Reportviewer but there's a strong likelihood that you have some temporary files that are still being referenced during setup.

Try cleaning out any files under C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local[AppFolderName] or C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Roaming[AppFolderName] manually. If that doesn't work, try using the cleanmgr.exe utility to do a cleanup and then try reinstall.

Comment: Clearing out the old files doesn't work. A friend found a similar StackOverflow question with an answer suggesting the problem has to do with signing keys. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222109/error-downloading-prerequisites-after-publishing-clickonce-application-from-vs-2