# Error downloading prerequisites after publishing ClickOnce application from VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, clickonce, prerequisites

For a software development project we have developed a setup , wherein prerequisite software's will be downloaded from vendors website. Prerequisites are .Net 4.5 and SqlLocalDB2012. But when setup runs it gets the following error.

[image]

Following is the final lines of install.log

```
    Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDEB2.tmp\"
Downloading files to "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDEB2.tmp\"
(1/12/2016 3:43:07 PM) Downloading 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=249113' to 'C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDEB2.tmp\'
Download completed at 1/12/2016 3:43:08 PM
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDEB2.tmp\DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
(1/12/2016 3:43:08 PM) Downloading 'SqlLocalDB2012\x64\sqlcmdlnutils.msi' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=299275&clcid=0x409' to 'C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDEB2.tmp\'
Download completed at 1/12/2016 3:43:09 PM
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDEB2.tmp\SqlLocalDB2012\x64\sqlcmdlnutils.msi
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
(1/12/2016 3:43:09 PM) Downloading 'SqlLocalDB2012\x64\sqllocaldb.msi' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=299278&clcid=0x409' to 'C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDEB2.tmp\'
Download completed at 1/12/2016 3:43:12 PM
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDEB2.tmp\SqlLocalDB2012\x64\sqllocaldb.msi
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Error: Setup has detected that the file 'C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDEB2.tmp\SqlLocalDB2012\x64\sqllocaldb.msi' has changed since it was initially published.
```

I have done both solutions on [setup has detected that the file "" has changed since it was initially published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463574/setup-has-detected-that-the-file-has-changed-since-it-was-initially-published) and [Error downloading prerequisites after publishing ClickOnce application from VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222109/error-downloading-prerequisites-after-publishing-clickonce-application-from-vs-2) . But I am still getting this error. Any idea how to make this work.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?